# htaccess Integrate add trailing slash to existing rules

Tags: .htaccess

I am doing several things in my htaccess file:

- forcing https
- removing www
- removing index.php

I'm using a proxy (Cloudflare)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

How can I integrate adding a trailing slash to my URLs? I have this snippet but of course simply adding it gives me multiple redirects:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing a slash in the second `RewriteCond`. This should work:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I also escaped the `.` in `index.php`.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to add the trailing slash function to the first code snippet, thus keeping the existing functions (forcing https, removing www, etc.)